# What is a radio echo?

Tags: radio

Simply that: what is a radio echo? And when it was first discovered?

By searching on Google I get results like Amazon Echo and Echo (radio station)

Comment: What do you mean by a 'radio echo' - please clarify.

Comment: @Jon Custer - _Stan Evans (..) developed the first of several VHF systems specifically for radio echo sounding in 1963. - Long delayed echoes (LDEs) are radio echoes.._ - So I am looking for a definition for "Radio echo"

Comment: https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/british-journal-for-the-history-of-science/article/accidents-and-opportunities-a-history-of-the-radio-echosounding-of-antarctica-195879/87FDD873A650C67555F168BD4DD00F70 and https://earthzine.org/a-brief-history-of-radio-echo-sounding-of-ice-2/ and https://www.jstor.org/stable/30165726?seq=1 might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a pulse of radio waves strikes an object which is electrically conductive, a portion of the wave train bounces off the object and returns towards its original source. That portion of the wave pulse is referred to as the *echo* or the *return*. A search on RADAR will furnish a detailed explanation, including the history of this phenomenon.